# Is there a way to fix my for loop to enable or disable an option based on a seperate list but not have potential of overriding

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have an array declared in my application properties for a spring boot app.
I am passing the list into the front end js and want to change one dropdown.When the change event fires I want it to look through a seperate dropdown and see if any options match my list. If they do I want them to be disabled, if not they should be enabled.

I have tried using a foreach nest but ended up switching back to for loop due to the HTMLOptions not being an array

```
for (var i = 0; i < workflow[0].options.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < validation.workflow.length; j++) {
        if (workflow[0].options[i].value == validation.workflow[j]) {
            workflow[0].options[i].disabled = false;
        } else {
            workflow[0].options[i].disabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The result of this is the disabled property being overridden due to an option being looped over multiple times looking at the two lists. The two lists are seperate lengths.

Comment: So, `validation.workflow` is an array?

Comment: @Bergi yes, sorry. validation.workflow is an array.

Comment: Good, then my answer below should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
for (const option of workflow[0].options) {
    option.disabled = validation.workflow.includes(option.value);
}
```